# How could I cast c++ const float* to char * type?

Tags: c++

This might be some duplicated question, but I have not find an answer to it, so I bother to ask it again. 
Suppose I have a function which return the data with an `const float*` type, how could I convert it to `char*` for `fstream.write` to use?

```
const float *ptr = nullptr;
some_func(ptr);
// my expected operator
fstream fout(...);
fout.write(ptr, 512);
```

How could I convert the `const float*` pointer to a normal pointer please?

Comment: What does it mean to convert a `const float*` to a `const char*`? You can always `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr)`, but there's no way that's what you want. What are you trying to accomplish? Just write a `float` to your file?

Comment: Yes, I need to write the data pointed by a `const float*` to a file. It seems that the `write` method only support `char *` pointer.

Comment: @coincheung Do you want to write the (binary) object representation of the pointed-to `float`(s) or the value of the `float`(s) formatted as text? Also, does the pointer point to an element of an array of floats? If so, how large is that array? Where does the number `512` come from?

Comment: Might be a useful thread on writing and reading pointers to files http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/33666/

Comment: @walnut Yes, it is an array of 512 float numbers, and I would like to regard them as binary bytes and dump them to a file.

Comment: Of note that this type of casting will write how the bytes appear ON THIS SYSTEM to your file. If another system that doesn't share the endianness attempts to read, you'll get an incorrect result. It's *likely* (but not guaranteed) that the two systems will represent floats as ieee 754 floats, but that's not guaranteed either.

Comment: @John Yes, thanks for reminding me this!!

Answer (score 2):

For your use case, the preferred method is to use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

```
fstream fout(...);
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(ptr), 512);
```

**PS**

If `ptr` points to an array of `512` number of `float`s, you'll have to use:

```
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(ptr), sizeof(float)*512);
```

Comment: There's no way this is what OP wants. What function returns a null-terminated float array, where the individual floats are not null-terminated, that needs to be serialized, as-is in memory, to an output file?

Comment: @John, I don't understand your concern regarding a null terminated float array.

Comment: my mistake, I thought `write` took up to `n` bytes OR until a null-terminator was encountered.

Comment: Oh thanks, is it possible to convert it to `char *` ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Becuase, apart from `write`, I remember I have met some other function that only supports `char*` rather than `const *char`.

Comment: I remember that I used `string str; func(str.data());` which gives me some error message, so I have to change it to `string str; func(&str[0]);`, so in case I met that problem again, would you tell me how could I convert it to `char*` ?

Comment: @coin you can use `const_cast` to add or remove constness. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast But this kind of low-level byte casting seems very dangerous to me, and if you don't know what you're doing, you can have nasty bugs that crop up tomorrow or (worse) next year.