# Is two static_cast better than reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, flatbuffers

I work with flatbuffers and need to write data to file. Flatbuffer struct returns uint8_t*, but std::ofstream::write takes char* as a parameter.
Could you tell me which approach using two static_casts or reinterpret_cast better and why?

```
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbBuilder // flatbuffer structer 
    ... // write something to fbBuilder
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    // this
    out.write(static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<const void*>(fbBuilder.GetBufferPointer())), fbBuilder.GetSize());
    // or this ? 
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(fbBuilder.GetBufferPointer())), fbBuilder.GetSize());
```

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based. IMO, it's better to be explicit about your intent and use `reinterpret_cast`. Double `static_cast` looks like a workaround for  code analyzer that warns about `reinterpret_cast` usages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700531/how-could-i-cast-c-const-float-to-char-type

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is best avoided.

Comment: @Ron, for writing to files and reading from files, `reinterpret_cast` is  appropriate.

Comment: Personally I would use `reinterpret_cast<const char*>`.  There is explicit language in the standard that you can iterate the by of an object when using a `char*` so it's "standard" way to do this.

Comment: Why casting two times ? Just cast to final type and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no added safety from the static casts in this case: A static cast from `void*` is equally dangerous as a reinterpret cast. In fact, reinterpret cast is defined in terms of casts through `void*`, so the examples are effectively identical in all but syntax.

The two static casts are longer and harder to read than the single reinterpret cast.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you don't need to cast to `const` in this example.  `GetBufferPointer()` returns a non-const `uint8_t*`, and you can pass a non-const `char*` to `ostream::write()`.  A pointer-to-non-const can be assigned to a pointer-to-const, the compiler will implicitly apply the `const` for you.  So a single cast will suffice, which in this case would require `reinterpret_cast` to cast from `uint8_t*` directly to `char*`:

```cpp
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(fbBuilder.GetBufferPointer()), fbBuilder.GetSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Double `static_cast` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> 5) Any object pointer type T1* can be converted to another object pointer type *cv* T2*. This is exactly equivalent to `static_cast< cv T2*> (static_cast< cv void*> (expression))` (which implies that if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's, the value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the *type aliasing* rules (see below)

It's idiomatic to use `reinterpret_cast` in this case, for example, the sample code for `ostream::write()` uses `reinterpret_cast`:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 0x41424344;
    std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof n) << '\n';

    char c[]="This is sample text.";
    std::cout.write(c,4)<<'\n';
}
```